Import maps using React Vite
I'm trying to use import maps with React and Vite. I have a React Vite application called app1 with the following vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { resolve } from "node:path";

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        [process.env.npm_package_name!]: resolve(__dirname, "src/main.tsx"),
      },
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "React-dom",
          "react/jsx-runtime": "react/jsx-runtime",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

This configuration generates the JavaScript and CSS files, as well as the manifest. After building, I upload the files to a local CDN server. When I navigate to http://localhost:8080/app1-D0fBYSKJ.js, I can correctly see the built code.
I also have a shell application that loads this app. To import the import map, I use the following code in the index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="module">
      async function loadAndApplyImportMap() {
        const response = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL}/get-import-map`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const importMap = await response.json();
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "importmap";
        script.textContent = JSON.stringify(importMap);
        document.head.prepend(script);
      }

      try {
        await loadAndApplyImportMap();
        import("./src/main.tsx");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

When I call get-import-map, I receive the apps in this format:
{
    "imports": {
        "app1": "http://localhost:8080/app1-D0fBYSKJ.js",
        "app2": "http://localhost:8080/app2-nsuvAHz_.js"
    }
}

I then attempt to load the application using the following code:
const RemoteComponentLoader = ({ packageName }: { packageName: string }) => {
  const Component = lazy(() => import(packageName));

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Component />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <RemoteComponentLoader packageName="app1" />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

However, I am encountering the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'app1'

What else am I missing? What are the steps to make import maps work with React and Vite?
I couldn't find an example of this approach, where I can build and import my applications using import maps.
I found this article: You Might Not Need Module Federation: Orchestrate your Microfrontends at Runtime with Import Maps | Mercedes-Benz.io, which is exactly what I want but it uses Vue and it didn't seem to work using React and Vite.
